# Show error "uninitialized constant Spree::ProductTaxon" while creating a row spree_products_taxons

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree

In my app, I am using spree gem. I want to store product_id and taxon_id in spree_products_taxons tables. But when I create, it shows above error. My code is like

```
def import
  require 'csv'
  file = params[:file]
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, encoding:'iso-8859-1:utf-8') do |row|

    @prod = Spree::Product.new()
    @prod.name = row["name"]
    @prod.shipping_category_id = row["shipping_category_id"]
    @prod.description = row["description"]
    @prod.available_on = row["available_on"]
    @prod.meta_description = row["meta_description"]
    @prod.meta_keywords = row["meta_keywords"]
    @prod.tax_category_id = row["tax_category_id"]
    @prod.shipping_category_id = row["shipping_category_id"]
    @prod.promotionable = row["promotionable"]
    @prod.meta_title = row["meta_title"]
    @prod.featured = row["featured"]
    @prod.supplier_id = row["supplier_id"]
    @prod.master.price = row["master_price"]
    @prod.master.cost_price = row["cost_price"]
    @prod.master.sku = row["sku"]
    @prod.master.tax_category_id = row["tax_category_id"]
    @prod.save!
    @prod_taxon = Spree.ProductTaxon.create(taxon_id: row["taxon_id"], product_id: @prod.id)
  end
  redirect_to admin_products_path, notice: "products imported."
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the latest [Spree::Taxon model](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/taxon.rb) and [Spree::Product model](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/app/models/spree/product.rb) from their [GitHub repository](https://github.com/spree/spree), it looks like you should be able to replace this part of your code:

```
@prod.save!
@prod_taxon = Spree.ProductTaxon.create(taxon_id: row["taxon_id"], product_id: @prod.id)
```

with this (untested)

```
@prod.save!
@prod_taxon = Spree::Taxon.find(row["taxon_id"])
@prod.taxons << @prod_taxon
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: when i applied it shows "unknown attribute 'taxon_id' for Spree::Taxon."

Comment: @vivek had another look at the model and edited my answer, see if that works